# How add white space under chapter heading in memoir class using pedersen chapter style?

Tags: formatting, memoir, chapters

I added a MWE at the bottom of the post. I want a little more white space under the title heading, because it feels a bit cramped the way it is now. Can someone help me with that?

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,14paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand\colorchapnum{\color{PineGreen}}
\renewcommand\colorchaptitle{\color{PineGreen}}
\chapterstyle{pedersen}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter heading}

    Words just under the chapter heading.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `0.5` with your preferred value

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,14paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand\colorchapnum{\color{PineGreen}}
\renewcommand\colorchaptitle{\color{PineGreen}}
\chapterstyle{pedersen}%
\renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{\par\nobreak\vskip0.5\midchapskip}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter heading}

    Words just under the chapter heading.

\end{document}
```